# Ruby and Sinatra problems with session

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra

I used sinatra session in my ruby project. After login I write in **session[:name]** the name of user. 
If user call some API method I verify **session[:name]** and if this value is not empty he get response from the server. After logout I clear this value.
My code:

```
 use Rack::Session::Cookie, :expire_after => 86400

    get '/login' do
        session[:name] = params[:username]
    end

    get '/logout' do
        session[:name] = ''
        return 'done'
    end

    error 401 do
      return '401 Unauthorized'
    end

    get '/check_session' do
        if session[:name].to_s.strip.length == 0 || session[:name].to_s!=params[:username]
            return 401
        end
        return session[:name]
    end
```

This code works good. But if I login from one browser, i.e. Google Chrome, and after that open anther browser, i.e. Mozilla FireFox and call **/check_session** I get response from server **401 Unauthorized**.
Why does this happen?
And how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not a bug. Each browser making own session. And you need to do login  after open page in new browser.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a bug, it's expected. A session only lives on **one** browser.When you launch Firefox, you start a new session. :)